# TextView in ToolBar moving to right on setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

Tags: android-studio, toolbar, android-toolbar

I am new to Android app development and using Android studio. I want to place a Textview in ToolBar. Here is my code of ToolBar xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FF5722"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Holler"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

On my first activity it is showing as expected in centre. But when I launch new Activity the TextView is moving to bit right. Here is my code for FirstActivity:

```
toolbarHome = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar_home); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
        setSupportActionBar(toolbarHome);

        final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
```

Please let me know if you require more code.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan no.. Not yet. Can you help me?...

Comment: yes. Are you using toolbar as a separate xml and set custom view or added as a part of the activity at the top

Comment: I created separate xml file for toolbar and used <include> to include toolbar in Activity.

Comment: @Rakesh did you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is the default behaviour of toolbar. It is because of the margins of the back button. If it is a simple text, you can use the toolbar title to set a textview.
But if you want to use your textview in the toolbar. You want to hide the back button by calling :

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Now you have to create your own back button by setting a ImageButton/ImageView with back arrow icon in the layout file along with your TextView to achieve the desired results.